# PHP remove first element of array and shift all others up 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$recent = apc_fetch('recn');
$recent[9] = $recent[8];
$recent[8] = $recent[7];
$recent[7] = $recent[6];
$recent[6] = $recent[5];
$recent[5] = $recent[4];
$recent[4] = $recent[3];
$recent[3] = $recent[2];
$recent[2] = $recent[1];
$recent[1] = $recent[0];
$rec = array_pop($recent);
$recent[0] = $name;
apc_store('recn', $recent);
```

Each time the page is reloaded, I wanted $name to be 1st, and than move whatever is 2nd down the list, and so on. I echo the array like so:

```
echo "Most Recent Songs: <br>";
echo "1. " . $name. "<br>";
echo "2. " . $recent[1] . "<br>";
echo "3. " . $recent[2] . "<br>";
echo "4. " . $recent[3] . "<br>";
echo "5. " . $recent[4] . "<br>";
echo "6. " . $recent[5] . "<br>";
echo "7. " . $recent[6] . "<br>";
echo "8. " . $recent[7] . "<br>";
echo "9. " . $recent[8] . "<br>";
echo "10. " . $recent[9] . "<br>";
```

But only the first entry shows up.

Comment: Instead of manually moving every element down an index in the array, try using `array_unshift`.

Comment: @giaour how would I do that?

Comment: I think you're also misunderstanding array_pop. You're taking the last element off and storing that in APC. Isn't it $recent that you want to store in APC?

Comment: you should invest in a loop

Comment: yes @Chelsea, what do you mean RUjordan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Thanks to @giaour for the array_unshift suggestion, and @Chelsea for helping me understand array_pop Heres my new (working) code:

```
$recent = apc_fetch('recn');
array_unshift($recent, $name);
$rec = array_pop($recent);
apc_store('recn', $recent);
```